# First-time backup landed in the wrong place

Tags: backup, cron, deja-dup

I used Backups with the following settings:

Folders to save: Home(jeg) [ON]

Folders to ignore: Trash, ~/Downloads [ON]

Storage location: 799 GB Volume [ON]

Folder: LinuxBackupDirectory [ON]

Scheduling: Every Week, Keep Forever [ON]

The Overview [also ON] said "Next backup is 5 days from now," but I clicked on "Back Up Now" just to make sure it's set up correctly.

The backup took about 3 hours.  I watched the list of files that were being backed up, and it seemed to be complete.  I also kept df'ing to see what was filling up, but for some reason, instead of my 799 GB volume being added on to, my root directory was.  The /tmp subdirectory was being periodically added on to, then emptied, but I couldn't find where everything was going.  At the end my root directory had grown by about 30 GB, and I expected that wherever the backed-up files were, they were now going to be moved into the Linux Backup Directory; but they never were.  I searched for them, and finally found a file in /home/jeg called "deja-dup," which contained a crontab file reading "1 0 * * 0 /usr/bin/deja-dup --backup," a file called "duplicity-full.20150516T130939Z.manifest," and all the backed-up files.

Now I can certainly move the manifest file, together with all the backed-up files, to where they were supposed to go.  But what do I have to change to make sure that they "always" land in my LinuxBackupDirectory folder?